# How to make query joins in cakePHP?

Tags: php, join, model, cakephp-2.1

I just wanna ask how to make query joins in CakePHP following this SQL syntax

```
SELECT a.id, SUM( r.jumlah_realisasi) AS jumlah_realisasi, SUM(b.jumlah_budget) AS jumlah_budget, SUM(c.jumlah_contrapos)
FROM accountposts a
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT accountpost_id, agency_id, SUM(budget_after_changes) AS jumlah_budget
FROM budgets
GROUP BY accountpost_id
) b
ON a.id = b.accountpost_id
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT accountpost_id, agency_id, SUM(realisation_value) AS jumlah_realisasi
FROM realisations
GROUP BY accountpost_id
) r
ON a.id = r.accountpost_id
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT accountpost_id, agency_id, SUM(contrapos_value) AS jumlah_contrapos
FROM contraposts
GROUP BY accountpost_id
) c
ON a.id = c.accountpost_id
GROUP BY
a.id
```

And I tried with this syntax (I use CakePHP 2.x):

```
$joins = array(
               array(
                  'table' => 'budgets',
                  'alias' => 'Budget',
                  'type' => 'LEFT',
                  'conditions' => array('Accountpost.id = Budget.accountpost_id')
                ),
                array(
                  'table' => 'realisations',
                  'alias' => 'Realisation',
                  'type' => 'LEFT',
                  'conditions' => array('Accountpost.id = Realisation.accountpost_id')
                ),
                array(
                   'table' => 'contraposts',
                   'alias' => 'Contrapost',
                   'type' => 'LEFT',
                   'conditions' => array('Accountpost.id = Contrapost.accountpost_id')
                ),
         );

        $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 60,
            'joins' => $joins,
            'fields' => array('Accountpost.id','Accountpost.explanation','Accountpost.account_code',
                              'SUM(Budget.budget_after_changes) AS jumlah_budget','SUM(Realisation.realisation_value) AS jumlah_realisasi','SUM(Contrapost.contrapos_value) AS jumlah_contrapos'),
            'group' => array('Accountpost.id'),
            'order' => array('Accountpost.id' => 'ASC'),
        );
```

And here is the SQL Dump from CakePHP :

```
SELECT `Accountpost`.`id`, `Accountpost`.`explanation`, `Accountpost`.`account_code`, SUM(`Budget`.`budget_after_changes`), `Budget`.`budget_after_changes`, `Realisation`.`realisation_value`, `Contrapost`.`contrapos_value` FROM `realisasi_anggaran`.`accountposts` AS `Accountpost` LEFT JOIN `realisasi_anggaran`.`budgets` AS `Budget` ON (`Accountpost`.`id` = `Budget`.`accountpost_id`) LEFT JOIN `realisasi_anggaran`.`realisations` AS `Realisation` ON (`Accountpost`.`id` = `Realisation`.`accountpost_id`) LEFT JOIN `realisasi_anggaran`.`contraposts` AS `Contrapost` ON (`Accountpost`.`id` = `Contrapost`.`accountpost_id`) WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Accountpost`.`id` ORDER BY `Accountpost`.`id` ASC LIMIT 60
```

But the result is different between SQL syntax version and CakePHP version, in SQL syntax there is no duplicated values while examining SUM, but in CakePHP version there are duplicated values while examining SUM. How do I implement my SQL syntax to cakePHP the right way?

Comment: you might want to cut down the codes that you have posted. You'll most likely get an answer if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$options` array is incorrectly constructed. This way the array has two nested, named keys called `joins` and Cake will not construct a correct SQL join.

The arrays should either look like this:

```
$joins = array(
  array(
    'table' => 'budgets',
    'alias' => 'Budget',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array('Accountpost.id = Budget.accountpost_id')
  )
);

$this->paginate = array(
  'limit' => 60,
  'joins' => $joins,
  'fields' => array('Accountpost.id','Accountpost.explanation','Accountpost.account_code',
                                  'SUM(Budget.budget_after_changes) AS jumlah_budget'),
  'group' => array('Accountpost.id'),
  'order' => array('Accountpost.id' => 'ASC'),
);
```

Or be constructed like the following:

```
$options = array(
  'limit' => 60,
  'fields' => array('Accountpost.id','Accountpost.explanation','Accountpost.account_code',
                                  'SUM(Budget.budget_after_changes) AS jumlah_budget'),
  'group' => array('Accountpost.id'),
  'order' => array('Accountpost.id' => 'ASC'),
);

$options['joins'] = array(
  array(
    'table' => 'budgets',
    'alias' => 'Budget',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array('Accountpost.id = Budget.accountpost_id')
  )
);

$this->paginate = $options;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's works. But i've got a problem when try to join more than one table, there are still duplicated values while examining SUM.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're calling the join now and what the duplicate values are.

Comment: sorry if my explanation made you confuse. Ok, i try to explain again, when i joined Table Accountposts & Budgets, everything is ok. But when i try to join Table Accountposts, Budgets, Realisations, Contraposts at the same time and the constructed as you explain above. there are duplicated values while examining SUM(Budget.budget_after_changes), SUM(Realisation.realisation_value), SUM(Contrapost.contrapos_value).

Comment: That might merit its own question as it isn't strictly about creating joins in Cake anymore, or you could update your question with the updated join code and the SQL generated that is generated.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve subqueries?

Comment: yes :), i read in CakePHP cookbook about subquery, and still confuse how to implement it in Join, The cookbook only give a example to implement subquery in Condition not in Join.